# Recorder/Mixer Bag

Tags: field-recording, mixer, kit-bag

Hi everyone,

Im in need of a decent bag to carry my Zoom H4N, PSC Mixer, Headphones, Spare cables etc. I know that portbrace do plenty but my budget wont stretch too much right now so i was wondering if anyone uses any alternatives such as camera bags or any cheaper options. Ideally id like a slot for my mixer and another similar slot incase i upgrade my recorder in the future.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with Petrol over portabrace. Biggest problem with Portabrace bags is how loud they are! They also aren't the easiest to configure. They like to be stubborn.

Petrol bags are awesome, and cheaper. Which PSC do you have?

If you have the DV mix 3, you can probably get away with the smallest bag ([here](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/686799-REG/Petrol_PS607_PS607_Deca_Mixer_Bag.html)), which is only $140. The next steps up aren't that much more expensive either.

Then again, if you aren't needed it to be wearable / accessible at the same time (ie just for   transportation), you can always go this route: [Part 1](http://www.sonic-terrain.com/2010/09/portage-i-the-mil-spec-way/), [Part 2](http://www.sonic-terrain.com/2010/10/portage-ii-the-ultralight-way/)

Happy Recording!

Comment: I'm also a happy user of the decca mixer bag. I've trusted it enough to work with the sea by the waist.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from dedicated sound bags (the Petrol range are very good)  its also worth checking out camera bags - a lot of those are very cleverly designed so as to be customised with internal divisions... Apart from a LowePro bag (with built in waterproof cover) I also just got a Denba satchel camera bag which was cheap (under $100) and best of all doesn't look like a camera bag... handy if you're not trying to draw attention to yourself!